# How to select by mathematical condition?

Tags: sql, r

I am learning to use SQL in R. I want to query a database about the mountains whose height is less than 100 meter difference from the average height of all mountains.

My code so far looks like this:

```r
sql6 = "SELECT Name, Height, AVG(Height) FROM mountain WHERE AVG(Height) > 100 AND AVG(Height) < 100" 

result6 = dbSendQuery(con, sql6)

df6 = dbFetch(result6)

head(df6)
```

But I get an error saying

> Error: Invalid use of group function [1111]

I have tried substituting the `AVG(Height) > 100` with `Height > 100` and the problem seems to be somewhere around there. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I don't think you can use `AVG(.)` as a `WHERE` conditional. It might be feasible to use `HAVING` or CTEs to do what you need.

Comment: Another thing: isn't `WHERE AVG(Height) > 100 AND AVG(Height) < 100` self-contradicting?

Comment: Your use of `Name, Height, AVG(Height)` is a little perplexing ... it seems like there should be grouping somewhere, but as it stands your `AVG(Height)` without grouping (if the query compiled, which it doesn't) would produce a single number for all rows, which seems not meaningful from a data standpoint. Can you provide some sample input data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `HAVING`. Using `sqldf` and `mtcars` ...

The base query:

```r
sqldf::sqldf("
  select cyl, avg(disp) as avgdisp
  from mtcars
  group by cyl")
#   cyl  avgdisp
# 1   4 105.1364
# 2   6 183.3143
# 3   8 353.1000
```

If we just want the higher two, then

```r
sqldf::sqldf("
  select cyl, avg(disp) as avgdisp
  from mtcars
  group by cyl
  having avg(disp) > 150")
#   cyl  avgdisp
# 1   6 183.3143
# 2   8 353.1000
```

An alternative:

```r
sqldf::sqldf("
  with cte as (
    select cyl, avg(disp) as avgdisp
    from mtcars
    group by cyl)
  select *
  from cte
  where avgdisp > 150")
#   cyl  avgdisp
# 1   6 183.3143
# 2   8 353.1000
```

I think this will apply just as well to other DBMSes, though un-tested.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `HAVING` as not `WHERE`

For your math. Use the difference between the height and the average and use the absolute  to check if it is lower than 100

```
  sql6 = "SELECT Name, Height, AVG(Height) FROM mountain HAVING  ABS(Height - AVG(Height)) < 100"
```